# Beautifulsoup, add attribute information (resource id) to url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Have a quick question, sorry couldn't figure it out from the manuals. I scrape a page and get an attribute value something along the lines of

```
div0 = soup.find('a')

print div0

>> <a href="/first/page"> some info </a>

resource0 = div0['href']

print resource0

>>  /first/page
```

...without the full url. I want to add the url at the beginning of 'resource0' above and then open it using urlopen and continue scraping. So for example if the url is https://www.website.com, i want to add the above resource0 onto it to make https://www.website.com/first/page and then be able to open the url.

Thanks in advance,

Vic

Comment: `div0['href']="http://site"+div0['href']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a base URL and join it with a relative one using [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin

base_url = 'https://www.website.com/'

div0 = soup.find('a')
resource0 = urljoin(base_url, div0['href'])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> base_url = 'https://www.website.com/'
>>> urljoin(base_url, '/first/page')
'https://www.website.com/first/page'
```